# Unable to set custom back button in Xamarin iOS master/detail app

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I've created a basic master/detail iOS (iPad/iPhone) app using Xamarin Studio Community 6.2, as described in the [Working with Tables in the iOS Designer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_5_-_creating_Tables_in_a_Storyboard/#Walkthrough) walkthrough. The project's freshly minted, so everything should be nice and dandy.

I'd like to set a custom back button title for my detail view (i.e. not "back" nor "[title of master page]"), yet I can't seem to find the rigth spot to make the incision.

I tried the `PrepareForSegue`-method in `MasterViewController.cs`:

```
    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        if (segue.Identifier == "showDetail")
        {
            var indexPath = TableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow;
            var item = dataSource.Objects[indexPath.Row];
            var controller = (DetailViewController)((UINavigationController)segue.DestinationViewController).TopViewController;
            controller.SetDetailItem(item);
            controller.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = SplitViewController.DisplayModeButtonItem;
            controller.NavigationItem.LeftItemsSupplementBackButton = true;

            // Me trying to set a custom back button title
            controller.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Custom back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
        }
    }
```

but to no avail.

Then I tried to set it in the `ViewDidLoad`-method in `DetailViewController.cs`:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Come on, this shouldn't be so hard?
        NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Custom back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);

        ConfigureView();
    }
```

but still no custom back button.

As a side-note, I'd like to mention that I tried to print out the navigation title both from the `MasterViewController.cs`

```
Console.WriteLine("Title: " + controller.NavigationItem.Title);
```

and from the `DetailViewController.cs`

```
Console.WriteLine("Title: " + NavigationItem.Title);
```

and they both worked fine, i.e. printed "Title: Detail" as expected to the console. In other words, the `NavigationItem`-object is set properly it seems.

What on earth did I miss here? Thanks!